# how to use groupby() in this case?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

let's say: there is a data frame:

```
country       edition  sports       Athletes               Medals
Germany          1990    Aquatics  HAJOS, Alfred           silver
Germany          1990    Aquatics  HIRSCHMANN, Otto        silver
Germany          1990    Aquatics  DRIVAS, Dimitrios       silver
US               2008    Athletics MALOKINIS, Ioannis      silver
US               2008    Athletics HAJOS, Alfred           silver
US               2009    Athletics CHASAPIS, Spiridon      gold
France           2010    Athletics CHOROPHAS, Efstathios   gold
France           2010    golf      HAJOS, Alfred           silver
France           2011    golf      ANDREOU, Joannis        silver
```

i want to find out Which edition distributed the most silver medals?
so i'm trying to solve it by groupby function in this way :

```
df.groupby('Edition')[df['Medal']=='Silver'].count().idxmax()
```

but its giving me

```
Key error = 'Columns not found: False, True'
```

can anyone tell me what is the issue?

Comment: it would be grate to see error too.

Comment: `df['Medals' == 'Silver']` is pretty much the same as saying `df[False]` since 'Medals' and 'Silver' are not the same thing. But `False` is not a column in your dataframe so it gives you that error. Try this: `df[df['Medals']=='silver'].groupby('Edition').count().idxmax()`

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence it is throwing this error

Comment: `df[df['Medals']=='silver'].groupby('edition')['Medals'].count().idxmax()`. Sorry 'Edition' is not a column so you can't group by that

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy thanxs for the minor correction but it should be size () in place of count()

Answer (score 3):

So here's your pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['Germany', 1990, 'Aquatics', 'HAJOS, Alfred', 'silver'], 
    ['Germany', 1990, 'Aquatics', 'IRSCHMANN, Otto', 'silver'], 
    ['Germany', 1990, 'Aquatics', 'DRIVAS, Dimitrios', 'silver'], 
    ['US', 2008, 'Athletics', 'MALOKINIS, Ioannis', 'silver'], 
    ['US', 2008, 'Athletics', 'HAJOS, Alfred', 'silver'], 
    ['US', 2009, 'Athletics', 'CHASAPIS, Spiridon', 'gold'], 
    ['France', 2010, 'Athletics', 'CHOROPHAS, Efstathios', 'gold'], 
    ['France', 2010, 'golf', 'HAJOS, Alfred', 'silver'], 
    ['France', 2011, 'golf', 'ANDREOU, Joannis', 'silver']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['country', 'edition', 'sports', 'Athletes', 'Medals'])
print(df) 

   country  edition     sports               Athletes  Medals
0  Germany     1990   Aquatics          HAJOS, Alfred  silver
1  Germany     1990   Aquatics        IRSCHMANN, Otto  silver
2  Germany     1990   Aquatics      DRIVAS, Dimitrios  silver
3       US     2008  Athletics     MALOKINIS, Ioannis  silver
4       US     2008  Athletics          HAJOS, Alfred  silver
5       US     2009  Athletics     CHASAPIS, Spiridon    gold
6   France     2010  Athletics  CHOROPHAS, Efstathios    gold
7   France     2010       golf          HAJOS, Alfred  silver
8   France     2011       golf       ANDREOU, Joannis  silver
```

Now, you can simply filter silver medals then `groupby` edition (note that `'Edition'` will throw a `KeyError` as opposed to `'edition'`) and finally get the count:

```
df[df.Medals == 'silver'].groupby('edition').count()['Medals'].idxmax()
>>> 1990
```

Comment: df[df['Medals']=='silver'].groupby('edition').size().idxmax() corrected now! it gives the same output as you.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by both columns to solve:

```
df[df['Medals'] == 'silver'].groupby(['edition','Medals'],as_index=True)['Athletes'].count().idxmax()

# Outcome:
(1990, 'silver')
```

Comment: 'Silver' is not a column :)

Comment: Corrected @Buckeye14Guy

Answer (score 0):

df[df['Medal']=='silver'].groupby('edition').size().idxmax()

I tried this and it worked! i just replaced count() by size()

Comment: look extremely like mine.

Answer (score 0):

You should count per edition per medal:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'edition':[1990,1990,1990,2008,2008,2009,2010,2010,2011],'Medals':['silver','silver','silver','silver','silver','gold','gold','silver','silver']})
>>> df['count'] = ''
>>> df['count'] = df.groupby(['edition','Medals']).transform('count')
```

Then do the filtering on max():

```
>>> df = df[df['Medals'].isin(['silver'])]
>>> df
   edition  Medals  count
0     1990  silver      3
1     1990  silver      3
2     1990  silver      3
3     2008  silver      2
4     2008  silver      2
7     2010  silver      1
8     2011  silver      1
>>> df = df[df['count'].isin([df['count'].max()])]
>>> df
   edition  Medals  count
0     1990  silver      3
1     1990  silver      3
2     1990  silver      3
```

or

```
>>> df[df['count'].isin([df['count'].max()])]['Medals'].unique()[0]

'silver'
```